# Resolving protocol names in custom tshark display filter

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I want to parse the standard header outputs of tshark. Since the default doesn't work, I am using a custom field parser that does *almost* the same thing. What I am missing is the resolution of the name of the protocol. My command is:

```
sudo tshark -b 256 -P -T fields -e frame.time_epoch -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e ip.proto -e ip.len -e col.Info -E separator=';' -b filesize:65535 -b files:10 -w tshark_tmp
```

This almost works, what I get is (this example is capturing two pings):

```
1378869929.862628000;192.168.78.252;192.168.78.53;1;84;Echo (ping) request  id=0x0abe, seq=65/16640, ttl=64
1378869929.863188000;192.168.78.53;192.168.78.252;1;84;Echo (ping) reply    id=0x0abe, seq=65/16640, ttl=64 (request in 1)
```

The same two pings look like this in the normal, no custom field tshark:

```
0.000000 192.168.78.252 -> 192.168.78.53 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0abe, seq=13/3328, ttl=64
0.000707 192.168.78.53 -> 192.168.78.252 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x0abe, seq=13/3328, ttl=64 (request in 1)
```

The main difference that I need to solve is in mine I get `84` for the protocol, whereas tshark prints `ICMP 98`. I could implement my own lookup table, but there is a large number of protocols and tshark already knows how to decode them, I just need to figure out how to get that in my parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the 1.11.x and 1.12 versions of `tshark`, the field names are `_ws.col.Protocol` and `_ws.col.Info`, instead of `col.Protocol` and `col.Info`.

Example:

```
tshark -T fields -e _ws.col.Protocol -e _ws.col.Info
```

Source: [col.Protocol missing from tshark 1.11.3 and 1.12.0-rc2](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10201)

Answer (score 1):

[Found the answer](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/23482/use-tshark-to-write-protocol-like-the-column-in-wireshark)

`-e col.Protocol`

Like always happens, you work on a problem for days, post the question then find the answer.